# Netflix filter / review downloads?

Tags: netflix

Is it possible to either filter or at least review Netflix movie downloads based on criteria like movie rating, nudity, obscenity, violence, etc?

Comment: What do you mean by reviewing movies based on those criteria?

Comment: reviewing downloads, i.e. categorizing previously downloaded movies based on those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. There are some options available. If you're looking at a movie's description, you can see what "kind" of a movie/show it is (this is under **This Movie Is:**). You can't get anything closer to what you're asking for but I usually use that as a pseudofilter.